# Energy saving mode on startup in Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, energy-saving

Everytime I start my Windows 8.1 system, the energy scheme is energysaving. Regardless of what I define as default, what was the last mode or whether a cable is plugged in or not.

What can this be and how can I ultimately tell Windows to only run on energysaving when no cable is plugged in?

The answers in [Windows 8 custom power plan keeps resetting itself](https://superuser.com/questions/631683/windows-8-custom-power-plan-keeps-resetting-itself) don't apply for my case, as neither ASUS nor Razer Game Booster are installed on my laptop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 custom power plan keeps resetting itself](http://superuser.com/questions/631683/windows-8-custom-power-plan-keeps-resetting-itself)

Comment: Have you set the options in the *Windows Control Panel | Power Options*, *Change plan settings* (you may have to do this for two or more plans, depending on which you use), *Change advanced settings*, and set each item in the list as needed? You can change which plan you're affecting from the drop-down at top.

Comment: What do you mean by "set each item in the list as needed", @DrMoishePippik?

Comment: You can alter the settings for *energysavings* to suit your needs. For example,  set *Sleep | Sleep after | On battery * to *20 minutes*, *Sleep | Sleep after | Plugged in *Never*. There are options to customize behavior on battery and plugged in as you want, whatever the nominal plan is labeled. For example, on my laptop, there's "Balanced", "eco", "High performance" and "Power Saver", but only "Balanced" is actually used.

Comment: Didn't work, doesn't work. It is set to *Never* for energysaving mode on cable. Regardless of *any* options I set, the energysaving mode is activated after boot has finished. Interestingly, during boot (right after I logged in), the activated mode is the mode I used in the last session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was similar to the linked question. Although I had long forgotten about the issue, I removed the previously installed third-party software shipped with the computer (in my case: Samsung). Among them were software to override Windows' power settings. Once installed, power settings worked as expected (= stopped resetting themselves after booting).